# Customize gitlab-runner-helper docker image to pull multiple private repositories?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-for-windows

I am new to docker, and I am currently trying to setup gitlab runner to run some tests in docker. The main problem here is that some of the tests require cloning/fetch from multiple private repositories other than the main project.

From my understanding, `gitlab-runner-helper` image does the cloning of remote git repository. But is it possible to customize `gitlab-runner-helper` to also do cloning for other git repository?

I have tried setting up git and doing the cloning/fetch within the docker container. While it seems like an option, but it requires a lot of extra work, and introduces potential security risks which I try to avoid.

I have also looked into git submodules, but it does not really fit into my use case.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your use case? what is in those other repos that you also need in this repo and if its needed why isnt it part of this repo. If its some shared code thats needed by lots of things why is it not packaged as an artifact and pulled in that way?

Comment: The main repo is somewhat public (some external devs have read-only access). For other repositories, they contain codes, tools, test data that we want to keep it internal only, hence the multiple repo setup.

Comment: Why are submodules not an option then? Looks like a good pick :p

Comment: @r4phG One main reason is due to the path and dependency setup between the repositories. Making them a submodule would mean a big revamp not only to our test scripts, but also for our build scripts, something we try to avoid due to limited development time.. Also some of the repos cannot be a submodule as this will mess up the code's library/package/import path.